# Will the rotating rod snap because of centrifugal force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation

> An elastic rod is rotating around an axis. The axis is at one end of the rod and is orthogonal to the length. The rod's length is $1.5 m$, Area is $0.8 cm^{2}$, density is $7000 kg m^{-3}$ and Young's modulus is $4.2×10^{9} N m^{-2}$. It's breaking force is 600 N and it has an angular velocity of $100 rad s^{-1}$.

Now the question is will the rod snap? So all of my class mates solved the problem assuming that all the mass is located at the end of the rod. But this is not true. Some mass is closer to the axis and somes is much further from the axis. So I have to make a differential equation (maybe) and then solve it to find the whole centrifugal force. But I am having trouble finding it. So can any one please point out what assumptions should I make and how it can be done? Or is there any other different approach to this Problem?

Comment: Not a differential equation but an integral equation. You need to get an expression for the force exerted by a small portion of the rod F(r) dr. Then integrate from the axis to the end.

Comment: @puppetsock What will be the upper and lower limit of F if I want to evaluate the integral for r=l to r=(l-x), where x is any constant number?

Answer (score 1):

Let some small arbitrary element on the rod be located at a distance $r$ from the axis. The centrifugal force on this element is 
$$dm \omega^2 r$$
Sum of the force on all such arbitrary elements will give you the centrifugal force.

Hope you can solve it from here.

Comment: What will be the limit of F if I want to evaluate the integral for r=l to r=(l-x), where x is any constant number?